# Should there be a tag for the 2020 US Presidential Election?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we create a tag to identify questions related to the 2020 Presidential General election, of which I assume we're likely to start seeing lots? Is it necessary to identify these kinds of questions with a specific tag for this specific event, or should we just keep using a combination of individual tags, on the theory (as @Philipp pointed out below) that most of the questions will be applicable to presidential elections in general.

There are 2 options that I see for tagging questions about this election:

1. Create a specific tag [2020-us-election](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2020-us-election), likely along with [presidential-election](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presidential-election) and [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states)
2. Make no changes, and use the combination of existing tags: [presidential-election](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presidential-election) + [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) + [donald-trump](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donald-trump) + [joe-biden](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joe-biden)

---

### Related Discussions:

#### [What should our standard be for event-specific tags?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4180/what-should-our-standard-be-for-event-specific-tags)

- This question says that it's ok to make event-specific tags, and the [trump-impeachment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trump-impeachment) tag has been added to 108 questions.

#### [Make le tag [presidential-election] specific again? Oui? Non?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/make-le-tag-presidential-election-specific-again-oui-non)

- This question discusses making [presidential-election](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presidential-election) country specific and decides not to, but it doesn't discuss tagging specific elections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if that tag would be useful. We didn't have a tag for the 2016 election either. How many questions will there be which are actually specific to the 2016 election in particular, and not [presidential-election](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presidential-election)s in general or about the candidates?

Comment: Probably a lot (though whether that should be the case is another question). We get a lot of questions about polling (ie, what's happened to the polls due to this event, why did this polling average change or not, etc.) and with COVID-19 there's likely to be questions specific to how this election will be carried out. I'm not sure if we should encourage these kind of current events questions, but we do seem to get a lot of them